# Simulation using Manipulate within Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

Suppose there is a list of matrices (say `m` matrices), `matC`. The first element of this list is considered as the *Benchmark* matrix with which the other $(m-1)$ matrices will be compared. One may call the other matrices as *Alternative* choices. I have the following `code` (`Manipulate` within `Manipulate`) to perform the comparison.

```
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[s];
 G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, 
   DirectedEdges -> True];
 a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
 t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
 matC = Table[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[
    KroneckerProduct[a[[i]], t[[i]]]], {i, 1, m}];
 Manipulate[
(* Problem 1: With Mathematica version 10: this `With` does not work. *)
  With[
   {wG = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*mat},
   With[{sqwG = wG.wG},
    Grid[{{Text["Matrix_wG"], Text["Square_sqwG"]},
      MatrixForm /@ {wG, sqwG}}]]
   ],
(* Problem 2: This `slider` is not working. *)
  {mat, matC, Slider}
  ],
 {{s, 1, "s"}, 1, 100, 1},
 {{m, 20, "m"}, 1, 20, 5},
 {{n, 10, "n"}, 5, 20, 5},
 {{d, 0.1, "d"}, 0, 1, 0.05}
 ]
```

The logic behing the above `code` is that I want to fix the values of the variables within the first `Manipulate`, such as fix `m`, `n`, `a`, `t`, etc. To do that, I created a slider for `SeedRandom[s]`. Then, in the second `Manipulate` I perform the comparison of *Benchmark* with the *Alternatives* through a slider for the variable `matC` created in the first `Manipulate`.

**Questions**:

1. Does `Manipulate` within `Manipulate` actually do what I just described above? Efficiency is not relevant in this question.
2. Is `Manipulate` within `Manipulate` an efficient way of performing the comparison concerned? If not, can you guide me to find the efficient ways?
3. I have two other technical problems with the above `code`, which are named inside the `code`. Can you also help me to solve these problems?

**Note**: I am using `Mathematica 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[s];
 G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges -> True];
 a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
 t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
 matC = Table[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[KroneckerProduct[a[[i]], t[[i]]]], 
   {i, 1, m}];
 Manipulate[With[{wG = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*matC[[mat]]}, With[{sqwG = wG.wG}, 
     Grid[{{Text["Matrix_wG"], Text["Square_sqwG"]}, MatrixForm /@ {wG, sqwG}}]]], 
   {mat, 1, Length @ matC, 1, Manipulator}], 
 {{s, 1, "s"}, 1, 100, 1}, {{m, 20, "m"}, 1, 20, 5}, {{n, 10, "n"}, 5, 20, 5}, 
 {{d, 0.1, "d"}, 0, 1, 0.05}, {matC, None}, {G, None}, {a, None}, {t, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am amazed with this speed of work. It works very nice. I wonder what `{matC,None}`, `{G, None}` etc does because changing parameters such as `n` or `m` already force a change in `G`, `matC` and so on. Is that related to the problem of _continuous updating_ of the variables in the first `Manipulate`?

Comment: @Tebernus, if  current value of `mat` is,say, 16, and `m` is 20, and `m` is reduced to `10` then an error message is issued (because `mat` becomes out of range). `{x, None}` trick also helps keep all variables inside Manipulate (without it `G`, `t`, `matC` ... would be global symbols).

Comment: Now I learned a new trick from you, a very useful piece of information that will help me in my current work. Many thanks.

Comment: Tebernus, you are most welcome.